# loglikelihood function is giving NaN values

Tags: r, optimization, mle

I have written a loglikelihood function in R using function() with 10 parameters and data as inputs. I am getting NA values when the likelihood function is computed at certain parameter estimates. The structure of the code is given below:

```
likelihood = function(p,data){
s=2
J=4
theta = p[1:s]
alpha = p[s+1:s+2]
mu = p[s+3:s+2+J]
r = p[s+3+J:s+4+J]
nj11 = data[1:J]
nj12 = data[J+1:2*J]
n1 = data[(2*J)+1]
n2 = data[(2*J)+2]
P1 = rep(0,J)
P2 = rep(0, J)
li = rep(0,J)
for(j in 1:J){

P1[j] = ... is defined as a function of p and data
P2[j] = ...is defined as a function of p and data
li[j] = sum( log(P1[j])*nj11[j] , log(1 - P1[j])*(n1-nj11[j]) , log(P2[j])*nj12[j] , log(1 - P2[j])* 
(n2-nj12[j]) )
}#End of j

likelihood = sum(li)
return(-likelihood)

}#End of function likelihood


likelihood(c(0.4,0.7,0.2, 0.2, .3,.4,.3,.4,.4,.6),c(nj11,nj12,n1,n2))
```

At some estimates of data values, likelihood gives NA. I cannot optimize this function as the objective function should have some finite value.

When I evaluate P1 and P2 manually at the same values (without defining function()), it is giving me sum(li) = -2223.436.

Is there any fault in defining the function?

Comment: Why have `P1[j] = ... is defined as a function of p and data`? Potentially impossible to spot any problems without all the code.

Comment: One thing I do notice straightaway though is you're probably not subsetting in the way you want to. Compare, for example, `p[s+1:s+2]` with `p[(s+1):(s+2)]`

Comment: @duckmayr Thank you very much for the observation. p[(s+1):(s+2)] worked.